# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' using OpenCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, object-detection

I am reading images from google drive mounted to google colab. I have two folders, one with positive covid-19 chest x-rays and another with normal chest x-rays. I am trying to show these images side-by-side for comparison. Here are images of the code and error:

[First Lines Of Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC2wz.png)

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLpJw.png)

Here is also the written code:

```
Cimages = ('/content/drive/My Drive/Data/Covid')
Nimages = ('/content/drive/My Drive/Data/Normal')

import skimage
from skimage.transform import resize
def plot(i):
  normal = cv2.imread(dataset +'Normal//' + Nimages[i])
  normal = skimage.transform.resize(normal, (150,150,3))
  covid = cv2.imread(dataset +'Covid//' + Cimages[i])
  covid = skimage.transform.resize(normal, (150,150,3), mode = reflect)
  pair = np.concatenate((normal, covid), axis = 1)
  print('Normal vs. Covid')
  plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
  plt.imshow(pair)
  plt.show()

for i in range(0,3):
  plot(i)
```

This gives me an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-237aff042641> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(0,3):
----> 2   plot(i)

<ipython-input-50-85bb2e03725c> in plot(i)
      3 def plot(i):
      4   normal = cv2.imread(dataset +'Normal//' + Nimages[i])
----> 5   normal = skimage.transform.resize(normal, (150,150,3))
      6   covid = cv2.imread(dataset +'Covid//' + Cimages[i])
      7   covid = skimage.transform.resize(normal, (150,150,3), mode = reflect)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/skimage/transform/_warps.py in resize(image, output_shape, order, mode, cval, clip, preserve_range, anti_aliasing, anti_aliasing_sigma)
     89     output_shape = tuple(output_shape)
     90     output_ndim = len(output_shape)
---> 91     input_shape = image.shape
     92     if output_ndim > image.ndim:
     93         # append dimensions to input_shape
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

So it seems to be occurring in the skimage.tranform.resize line of code. Please help.

Comment: Try to add code snippets instead of their picture

Comment: As you can see, I added both. Have picture of the code and error, also the snippets.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the function

```py
skimage.tranform.resize
```

but with the reading of the image

```py
normal = cv2.imread(dataset +'Normal//' + Nimages[i])
```

not sure what are you trying to do there but `Nimages[i]` won't give you first file in a folder but it will yield first character of a string, in your case `/`. Then you will send `dataset` variable + `Normal//` + `/` which is basically in your case `Normal///` and then you will try to read image on that path, but without doubt the is no image there in which case `opencv` will return to you `None` (which is basically nothing). and then you try to resize `None` with `skimage` which will fail.

better option would be to read the image directly or in a loop that could look somehow like this:

```py
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(Nimages) if isfile(join(Nimages , f))]
for image_path in onlyfiles:
    normal = cv2.imread(join(Nimages , image_path))
    normal = skimage.transform.resize(normal, (150,150,3))
```

assuming that there are only images in your mentioned directory.